# Ideas for sampling design

Tags: sampling, stratification, cluster-sample, survey-sampling

I have a data base of schools per district and the number of teachers per school. I want to select a sample where between 1 an 10 schools are selected in each district. Once a school is selected, the number of teachers selected should be proportional to the total number of teachers in the sample.

As we see, the districts are stratums, and the schools too.

EDIT:  The maximum error of the proportion sholud be 0.035 and a 95% intervale confidence. I'm new to probabilistic sampling.

Is there any good tutorial or some advice to select the sample?

Comment: Please tell us the purpose of this sampling.  It might also be useful to explain why you are limiting the numbers of schools to this range from one through ten.

Comment: It's a university project and the requirement of the teacher is that between 1 an 10 schools per district should be selected. The purpouse is to conduct a survey.

Comment: Nobody conducts a survey just to conduct a survey: surveys are administered in order to learn things about the subjects surveyed and, through them, about the populations from which they were selected.  *What* you want to learn determines, in part, what a good sample design will be.  Other determinants include your expectations about the subjects' responses and the costs of administering the surveys.  Since it is a school project, please consult our [self-study wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and apply its recommendations to how you frame this question.

Comment: I would like to have  more information too but I don't have information about the costs. The information I have is just what I wrote, and the maximum error of the proportion sholud be 0.035 and a 95% intervale confidence. I'm new to probabilistic sampling.

Comment: Thank you for that additional information: you might want to include it in your question when you edit it.

Comment: The statement "the number of teachers selected should be proportional to the total number of teachers in the sample" cannot be correct, as it is a tautology.  I surmise that the word should be "population".

Comment: While this is a relatively standard sampling project, I feel like writing a whole tutorial on this is somewhat onerous. @CreamStat would be best off relating this to a survey statistician consultant. Doing this on one's own requires a sequence of say [Lohr (2009)](https://www.amazon.com/Sampling-Analysis-Advanced-Sharon-Lohr/dp/0495105279) or a similar book followed up by [Valliant et. al. (2013)](https://www.amazon.com/Practical-Designing-Weighting-Statistics-Behavioral/dp/146146448X/) with practical suggestions and `R` code.

Comment: To clarify, this is a two-stage sample. The first stage are schools, and this stage is stratified by district. I.e., the districts act as strata, and within each district, a sample of schools is selected. Teachers within schools form the second stage of sampling. The issue of sample size calculation is complicated by the intra-class correlation of teachers within schools, which may or may not be known.